# Should I use a huge delegator to keep my code decoupled?

Tags: class-design, single-responsibility

I am currently learning to apply the SRP and decouple code. But I found that having a lot of small classes blows up constructors of my classes. And it feels like code that uses another module of my application has to know more of that module than I like to know it.
I found that many books mention that classes should be really small, **but not how to manage that amount of small classes.**

---

Lets assume I have a module in my application that is concerned with casting content to a remote device (like Chromecast).
Now I have tried to separate my responsibilities as much as I could.

There is a `CastErrorEventDispatcher`, `CastSessionHelper`, `CastRequestSender`, `CastConnectivityHelper` and many many more.

Now the other parts of my application need access to different objects of my cast module.  Some need only one class other might need 4.  This definitely blows up constructors.

like this:

```
public class ExpandedControlsPresenter(){
    public ExpandedControlsPresenter(CastRequestSender castRequestSender,
                                     CastConnectivitySender castConnectivitySender,
                                     CastBreakEventDispatcher castBreakEventDispatcher, ...){
    ...
    }

    public void setUp(){
        castBreakEventDispatcher.addListener(...);
        castRequestSender.addListener(...);
    }
}
```

This concerns me because now my presenter has to know so much stuff about the casting classes.
So I wonder if it would be better to hide the whole cast module behind one big delegator.

```
public class CastManager {
    //Constructor with all relevant cast classes


    public void addBreakEventListener(CastBreakEventListener listener){
        castBreakEventDispatcher.addListener(listener);
    }
}
```

And then just have this in my presenter

```
public class ExpandedControlsPresenter(){
    public ExpandedControlsPresenter(CastManager castManager, ...){
    ...
    }

    public void setUp(){
        castManager.addBreakEventListener(...);
        castManager.addRequestSenderListener(...);
    }
}
```

This has the advantage of getting smaller constructors and I could turn the casting feature on and off by just interacting with the `CastManager`. But if course the `CastManager` would become incredibly huge.

---

Is there a good way of dealing with this problem?

**Edit:**
I drew a quick diagram to hopefully clarify my intentions. Also want to say that I know `manager` is not a good name.

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason it's better for a "manager" to have lots of dependencies than a presenter?

Comment: If what worry you is the construction, I would suggest to look for Creational Patterns. Managers are not designed to make smaller constructors. They have a whole meaning and functionality by theirown. Making easier to initialize your Presenter is another story.

Comment: For the "manager" it is not but for the rest of the application it would be better because it only has to interact with one class to handle casting. At leat I think so, but thats why I asked, I am not sure.

Comment: I think your approach is good. If you have multiple interfaces that work together, then is better to create a façade over them. This is what you did. I would remove the `Helper`, `Manager` and `Dispatcher` suffixes to have a cleaner code.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a situation where you've gone a step too far!  I find that when I wind up with a ton of settings classes (like the names CastRequestSender and CastConnectivitySender lead me to believe they are), **I like to wrap them in one big object called a Container to keep myself sane.**

So, if you find yourself with all these, perhaps you want to add something like this:

```
public class CastSettingsContainer{
    CastRequestSender requestSender;
    CastConnectivitySender connectivitySender;
    //And so on...
}
```

This means you now have an object who's entire purpose is to contain an entire set of Cast Settings.  This also helps you decouple code, because other classes now don't necessarily have to know about the individual Cast settings, just the container object.  This way, you can neatly have other classes ask a CastSettingsContainer to do stuff, and he internally can manage what's going on with the different settings.  This should clean your code up pretty well by eliminating a lot of weird constructors and moving them into the Container.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but these classes are not just for settings. They all handle different logic for casting content.

Comment: Oh, even better then!  I just used settings as an example, since that's what I could see. Hopefully what I was getting at makes sense: you're going to make an object that's entire purpose is to manage the bits of the Cast itsself.

Comment: All you're doing there is hiding the code smell - that your class has way too many dependencies. I suspect this ends up with lots of getter usage on the new class and no encapsulation to speak of, thus adding a lot of coupling.

Comment: @MrCochese can you explain that more? I was attempting to imitate a UnityContainer, but it looks like I'm off course.  The thought was that no classes outside of the Container know about the internal classes, so that decouples the code a bit more.  IE a display now has no idea that the ConnectionSettings are even there.

Answer (score 0):

Given this:

```
castManager.addBreakEventListener(...);
castManager.addRequestSenderListener(...);
```

why not just register dependent classes as a collection of *listeners*. That way, you don't have specific sets of classes that you're injecting into your 'container', but a list of interested parties.

When an event occurs, you can then 'publish' an event, and the registered listeners can then act on that event, or ignore it if they wish e.g. (in pseudo-code)

```
for (listener : listeners) {
   listener.startupEvent(myStartupEvent);
}
```

Some components would care, others wouldn't. You may have different sets/types of events, and consequently you may wish to have different registrations (e.g. I want to register for events of *category X*, but not of *category Y*, so you may want different collections of listeners...)

I find this a powerful way to combine multiple components. It's flexible (you just add a new listener and/or a new event type) and you don't suffer the explosion of component dependencies and members. The downside is that you have to make sure your component is correctly 'wired' together, since you lose the static typing that ensures `typeA` is constructed with a `typeB`